# Como criar "grid" com elementos flutuantes semelhante ao Pinterest

Tags: html, css, css3, grid

Olá, estou a criar uma *grid* com `divs` a flutuar à esquerda, porém quando chega à quinta `div` no bloqueio de `1000px`, ela flutua à direita e não à esquerda como deveria ser e a `margin-top` fica maior para todas as `divs` seguintes, ou seja a partir do quinto elemento, as `divs` seguintes ficam com um grande espaçamento no seu topo.

Vejam no exemplo desta imagem abaixo:

[image: aqui está a ilustração do problema]

E eu quero que elas fiquem assim:

[image: Como deveria ficar]

E o código que estou utilizando é esse:

HTML

```
<div class="center">
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="boxpost">
            <img src="https://33.media.tumblr.com/26bf1c7107a9a765bd28aeabd15dfec5/tumblr_nwyd2kKcpH1u24qqvo1_400.gif" width="239px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1024px;
}
.boxpost{
    width:245px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19) !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.profilepost{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

---

O problema é que eu tenho que tirar as heights e sempre colocar o overflow auto, porque podem vir imagens de tamanhos diferenciados, e até mesmo para a estética do negócio ficar mais descontraida dai coloquei overflow auto e temos um novo problema, as divs se misturam, tipo coloco 4 divs com imagens diferentes, a quarta div vira a segunda no site, e tudo fica embaralhado.

Comment: Boa noite, poste o html e css de maneira que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Boa noite, sobre a indentação e marcação basta olha no momento da edição um icone com sinal de interrogação que fica na parte superior do editor de texto do stackoverflow, nele tem dicas de como formatar.

Answer (score 6):

Para fazer isso tens que utilizar a propriedade [**`column-count`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp) em vez do `float:left;` como no exemplo abaixo. Esta propriedade divide o conteúdo dentro de uma `div` no qual esta propriedade é atribuída, em várias colunas dependendo do valor que lhe aplicarmos (ex: `column-count: 3;`).

Infelizmente, nem todos os elementos fluem como deve ser quando aplicada esta propriedade, mas felizmente temos a solução para isso que é utilizar a propriedade `break-inside`, nos elementos que se encontram dentro de um *layout* de colunas.

Eis um exemplo abaixo deste *layout* de colunas em funcionamento e já preparado para ecrãs de pequenas e grandes resoluções:

> Tens aqui também um [exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6g8amwp/) se preferires.

```css
#colunas {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 15px;
}
.boxpost {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #936C6C;
    margin: 0 2px 15px 2px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
.maior{height:150px;}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #colunas {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #colunas {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="colunas">
    <div class="boxpost"></div>
    <div class="boxpost maior"></div>
    <div class="boxpost"></div>
    <div class="boxpost maior"></div>
    <div class="boxpost"></div>
    <div class="boxpost maior"></div>
    <div class="boxpost"></div>
    <div class="boxpost maior"></div>
    <div class="boxpost"></div>
</div>
```

> Referências: [CSS3 column-count Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp), [break-inside](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)

### Existe também o plugin - [Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) em jQuery,

que faz este mesmo trabalho ligeiramente diferente, se preferires.

Para utilizar o plugin basta o implementares no `<head>` do teu site como (e juntamente com) a [Biblioteca jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) com a seguinte linha de código:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Depois basta criares as tuas `divs`, por exemplo:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

e apontá-las para utilização do plugin com este bocado de código jQuery da seguinte forma:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

Podes ver um exemplo do plugin em funcionamento aqui neste link: http://jsfiddle.net/rgzsxayn/

> Podes saber mais sobre o plugin e ler a sua documentação aqui: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
>   Disponível no Github: [Masonry no Github](https://github.com/desandro/masonry)